# Single Table Inheritance in Sequel::Model (Ruby ORM)

Tags: ruby, orm, model, sequel, default-scope

I have a table in my database called `providers` with a type column called `provider_type`.  `provider_type` can be either of the following:

- center
- sponsor

I want to create a class that inherits from `Sequel::Model` called `Center` and one called `Sponsor`, the resulting methods for which will scope all queries for the respective class by `provider_type = 'center'` or `provider_type = 'sponsor'`.

It's not 100% essential that I be able to do this but if it is possible, it would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the single_table_inheritance plugin:

```
class Provider < Sequel::Model
  plugin :single_table_inheritance, :provider_type
end
class Center < Provider
end
class Sponsor < Provider
end
```

This will work, but only if the provider_type column matches exactly "Center" or "Sponsor".  If not, you might need to add a :model_map option to the plugin call.  The documentation on this plugin is located at http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/SingleTableInheritance.html

Comment: that's even cleaner than I hoped it would be.  Thanks!